# Personal Tax Deduction for written work to a recognized 501c3

Tags: united-states, income-tax

If a recognized charity is willing to purchase original written works from me, may I opt to donate the written work and take it as an itemized deduction on my personal income taxes? 

**Country: USA

State: GA**

Answer (score 1):

### Unlikely.

If it's work you'd be producing specifically for this organization, that would not be deductable. Per [Publication 526, Charitable Deductions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2016_publink1000229698), "You can't deduct the value of your time or services, including: … The value of income lost while you work as an unpaid volunteer for a qualified organization."

On the other hand, if you were say an author of a published book or something (not specifically written for this organization), you could donate a copy of the book and probably deduct its fair market value (or perhaps only your basis, [if it's your business's inventory](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p526/ar02.html#en_US_2016_publink1000229740)).